# Pari compatibility with C++ classes

Tags: c++, class, pari

I'm writing a program using Pari and used classes to code conveniently, but it seems that Pari is not compatible with C++ classes. I made a class that had a GEN variable and initialized it using the constructor. Every time I try to access that variable, program shows a segmentation fault.
Is there a way to make it compatible with C++?
Is there a patch to add further functionality to Pari?

This is an example of the code I'm trying to run.

```
#include <pari/pari.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test{
public:
    GEN x;

    Test(){
        x = cgetg(5, t_VEC);
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            gel(x, i + 1) = gen_0;
    }

    void exp(){
        cout << GENtostr(x) << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    pari_init(600000000, 2);
    Test y;
    y.exp();
    pari_close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In general it's possible to call c code from c++. Could you give a specific sample that reprodces your problem please?

Comment: With a "It doesn't work" questions, you should as @πάνταῥεῖ stated provide a minimal reproducing case.

Comment: I instantiated the GEN vector through an array. That solved the problem.
Thanks! :)